Is there any way to engrave text into a cube and keep the text editable?
I have created a cube, which is styled as a stone.
Also I have created a (styled) text object with extrusion, which I would like to engrave into the cube until about half the thickness of the cube.
The only way I found so far was to convert the text to a mesh and use the boolean modifier to calculate the difference.
However, with that I loose the option to edit the text.
Is there any more convenient way to have an editable text engraved into a stone/ cube, beside developing a plugin-in?
Right now, whenever I want to change the text, I have to memorize all the things I did afterwards and redo them, which is not that great.

You can also generate the text within Geometry Nodes:

This setup makes sure the extruded geometry is manifold. The attribute stat part makes sure the merging distance is adjusted to the scale of the text.
As opposed to Gordon's answer, here I don't use the boolean - you can use the normal modifier. In Gordon's answer you also don't need to use the "Mesh Boolean" node, you could just have a very simple geonodes setup to convert the text to mesh:

and then use the boolean modifier as usual.

@GordonBrinkmann I wouldn't say one method is better than another. Long term it's probably a good idea to learn geonodes workflow, but if you have deadlines you might want a minimal solution in geonodes and continue using the vanilla text, vanilla boolean modifier, vanilla animation system (that one clearly is better for arbitrary animations...)
